# Can't read temperature from Adafruit RTD 3 wire sensor and max31865 chip

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, adafruit, circuitpython

I'm trying to read temperature from a 3-wire PT100 sensor and max31865 chip.
The chip has the correct jumpers soldered to define it as 3 wire.

I have tried to follow [these instructions](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max31865-rtd-pt100-amplifier/python-circuitpython) as closely as possible.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B, with the latest Bookworm default Pi OS installed.
I am connected to the Pi over SSH from the terminal via Wifi from a MacBook Pro, not using the GUI in any way.

Becuase Bookworm requires a virtual environment, I have set that first in this way:

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
python -m venv --system-site-packages env
source env/bin/activate
```

From 'sudo raspi-config' I have done the following:

```
In interface options - enabled SPI interface
In interface options - disabled "shell messages on the serial connection"
In interface options - enabled "serial port hardware"
```

Then rebooted and re-enabled the virtual environment.

My sensor hardware is wired the same [as shown in the adafruit documentation](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/59537) except that I'm using a different ground pin (physical pin 6 instead of pin 9).

[image: pinout from adafruit for max31865 connections]

I have installed the max31865 module in the virtual environment like this without errors:

```
pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-max31865
```

When I run [their suggested](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max31865-rtd-pt100-amplifier/python-circuitpython) code, I am using physical pin 29 (GPIO 5) as my Chip Select pin.

I'm also trying to keep pin GPIO27 low, and set as an output.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import board
import digitalio
import adafruit_max31865
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # Import Raspberry Pi GPIO library
#pin definitions
led_pin37 = 26
# Suppress warnings
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
# Use "GPIO" pin numbering
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
# Set GPIO pin 26 or Pin D37 as output
GPIO.setup(led_pin37, GPIO.OUT)
# Create sensor object, communicating over the board's default SPI bus
spi = board.SPI()
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5) # Chip select of the MAX31865 board.
sensor = adafruit_max31865.MAX31865(spi, cs, rtd_nominal=100, ref_resistor=430.0, wires=3)
# Note you can optionally provide the thermocouple RTD nominal, the reference
# resistance, and the number of wires for the sensor (2 the default, 3, or 4)
# with keyword args:
# sensor = adafruit_max31865.MAX31865(spi, cs, rtd_nominal=100, ref_resistor=430.0,wires=2)
# Main loop to print the temperature every second.
while True:
    GPIO.output(led_pin37, GPIO.LOW)  # Turn GPIO 26 or pin 37 low 
    # Read temperature.
    temp = sensor.temperature
    # Print the value.
    print("Temperature: {0:0.3f}C".format(temp))
    # Delay for a second.
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

When I run this using python mycode.py

I get a continuous incorrect reading from the temperature sensor, (it doesn't change if I warm the sensor with my fingers):

```
Temperature: -242.020C
Temperature: -242.020C
Temperature: -242.020C
Temperature: -242.020C
Temperature: -242.020C
```

I've also tried modifying the code so that the Chip Select pin is defined as D29 instead of D5 (my Chip Select pin is wired to physical pin 29):

```
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D29) # Chip select of the MAX31865 board.
```

Which immediately gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'board' has no attribute 'D29'. Did you mean: 'D19'?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Photo of the max31865 chip
[image: max31865 chip]

Photo of the Pi board
[image: pi board]

Comment: CircuitPython is designed to run on microcontroller boards. 
It is possible to force it to run on a Pi (but few experienced users use it). Have you installed Blinka?

Comment: On a previous setup I tried installing Blinka. It installed what looked like a lot of uneccessary modules (Chromium? Plex?), and then I had the same issue. Am I approaching this the wrong way? What is the correct way to get this probe to read using a Pi in python?

Comment: I can't really say as I haven't used CircuitPython or a Max31865. You appear to be trying to mix Python & CircuitPython but they are different. If I were doing this I would search for a normal Python module (or write one).  I find the Adafruit documentation and instructions very confusing. Adafruit seem to be the only people to use CircuitPython.